# calling multiple sidekiq workers from a worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis, sidekiq

I have to run multiple jobs upon a request from the user. However only one is important among those.

So i have a `MainWorker` in whose `perform` method I call different other workers like `Worker1`, `Worker2`.

Worker1 and Worker2 can be delayed, I need to give priority to MainWorker.

so here is how my perform method looks now

```
class MainWorker
 def perform( user_id ) 
   User.find( user_id ).main_task
   Worker1.perform_async( user_id ) 
   Worker2.perform_async( user_id ) 
 end
end
```

I might have more sub workers coming up later.  I want to know if this is a good practice or there is a much better way to do this. I however give custom queue names and priority to those based on the worker.

Comment: Do you need to run Worker1 and Worker2 right after main_task? Or maybe all of them can be run simultaneously?

Comment: they can be delayed, they need not run simultaneously, but Worker1 and Worker2 has to run only after MainWorker perform method is completed i.e., the main task.

Comment: So, I don't see any much better solution for your pproblem

Comment: `perform_aync`??? don't you mean `perform_async`?

Answer (score 2):

There are some 3rd party add-ons for Sidekiq. See here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Related-Projects

One that might be helpful for you is: [SidekiqSuperworker](https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker).